# How do multi-gem Ruby projects like Rails manage parallel development of each gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependency-management

I've started working on project with a plugin host and several plugins, where plugins can depend on each other.  Consequence is that one gem has a dependency on one or two others, where features may be evolving in parallel.  What is the best way to manage this?

Main options I've seen:

1. Build and install gems; seems a little heavyweight.
2. Append to the test paths in the Rakefile, which depends on local filesystem.
3. Bundler, which has overhead we're trying to avoid, and would once again involve references to local paths in a committed file.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler's Gemfile.lock doesn't reference local paths.
It's a snapshot of all of the gems and versions that it installed.
You should always commit both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

You can also use the :git option to point a git repo in your Gemfile.

`gem "my_plugin", :git => "git://example.com/my_plugin.git"`

This way you won't have to build gems.

You can always update the plugin to the latest version:

`bundle update my_plugin`

Comment: Actually, it can reference local paths, it's just not how one ultimately want's to publish it.